# hash_hmac() functionality

Tags: php, linux

I'm tying out a new moodle module, which provides integration with Windows Live.

When using the live authentication I get a blank page.  Switch on PHP error logging and get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash_hmac() in /srv/www/htdocs/moodle/auth/liveid/windowslivelogin.php on line 1293
```

Line 1293 is: `return hash_hmac("sha256", $token, $signkey, true);`

I have compiled PHP with the mhash extension.

My question is how can I test hash_hmac() functionality on my server?

Cheers,

Nathan.

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: PHP 5.1.2 (from the SUSE repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add hash to PHP in SUSE 10.2

zypper install php5-devel

pecl install hash

add extension = hash.so to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

restart apache

Answer (score 1):

It looks like hash_hmac() is in the [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) extension not mhash, although apparently by default it is enabled since 5.1.2 (https://www.php.net/releases/5_1_2.php).

Comment: The extension is shipped with PHP since version 5.1.2.